# OpenGL - Point light shader outputting white

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, normals

In my per-vertex point lighting implementation, every fragment output is white, and I am having trouble locating the source of the problem.

[image]

I closely followed [this](http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/per-vertex-lighting/) tutorial for the shader code, so I think the problem may stem from my vertex normals.

The scene is comprised from planes (2 triangles each). The normal for each plane is based on it's four corners and it is this normal vector I am passing to the shader for each vertex. Normal directions shown below.

[image]

However, after a lot of research, it seems this is the correct technique for calculating normals. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix; 
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix; 

in vec3 in_position;
in vec2 in_texcoords;
in vec3 in_normals;

out vec3 vPosition;
out vec2 vTextureCoord;
out vec3 vNormal;

void main(void)
{
    vPosition = vec3(modelViewMatrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0));
    vTextureCoord = in_texcoords;
    vNormal = vec3(modelViewMatrix * vec4(in_normals, 0.0));

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330

precision mediump float;

in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec4 finalColor;

uniform sampler2D MyTexture0;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(8.2, 0, 3);

    float distance = length(lightPosition - vPosition);
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPosition - vPosition);
    float diffuse = max(dot(vNormal, lightVector), 0.1);
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));

    vec4 fragmentColor = texture(MyTexture0, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));

    finalColor = fragmentColor * diffuse;
}
```

The scene as displayed with a basic shader, no lighting calculations.

[image]

Comment: If you disable the lighting, does your mesh still white? Are you sure that your normal are normalized?

Comment: When the lighting is disabled the mesh renders correctly, and the normals are all normalised to a length of one before being sent to the shader. Any ideas?

Comment: If I were you, I would try to force the normalization into the fragment shader :
float diffuse = max(dot(normalize(vNormal), lightVector, 0.0);

You don't use the good normal transformation in your vertex shader. The normal matrix should be the transpose of inverse of modelview matrix.
So I would do something like that : vNormal = transpose(inverse(mat3(modelViewMatrix))) * in_normals.xyz;

Comment: However, I advice you to prefer deferred lighting instead to perform lighting withing the geometry pass

Comment: White is usually what OpenGL makes things when the fragment shader is invalid (although I think the vertex shader will do the same). Did it compile and did the program link properly?

Comment: Yeh it compiles properly. The white visibly changes to black as you turn your back towards the light source, suggesting a calculation issue.

Comment: I'd say try normalizing your normals, to be sure that they are unit normals. Big normals essentially "scale" your light, so it might explain the extreme brightness. However, don't do deferred rendering, that's just a silly suggestion. It's like: Q: "hey my ford's windshield wiper broke" A: "Buy a ferrari"

Comment: If you have any scaling in your model view matrix then this could cause the big normals. Just wrap the normal calculation in the vertex shader in a normalize() call. As a debug tool, I find it useful to output a variable as the color to check if it has the values I want. For instance, if you output the normal as a color, you can see which direction it points at. Red is positive X, Green positive Y etc. Hope it helps!

Comment: I looked into deferred rendering, overkill. Normalizing the normals makes everything black, the one thing worse than everything white :/ The normals are unit vectors when I pass them to the vs shader, and I guess the fs shader skews them during interpolation. I'll look into Atonine's suggestion, inverse normals.